# Defining colors as constants in C#

Tags: c#, colors, compile-time-constant

I've set up some default colors in a C# winforms application like so:

```
readonly Color ERROR = Color.Red;
readonly Color WARNING = Color.Orange;
readonly Color OK = Color.Green;
```

As far as I am aware, readonly is essentially a constant for my purposes. If I attempt to define these as constants, the compiler indicates that it must be a compile-time constant, which Color is not.

Am I good leaving these as-is, or is there some way to define these constants that I should be aware of?

*(The purpose is simply to have a single location in which to change all of the colors for logging purposes.)*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only literals can be defined as `const`. The difference is, that `const` values are **hard-bakened** into the assemblies that uses it. Should their definition change, then the call sites doesn't notice unless they get recompiled.

In contrast, `readonly` declares a variable in a way that it cannot be reassigned after outside the **constructor** (or static constructor in case of a `static readonly` variable).

So, you have no other way then to use readonly here, since Color is a struct, and no primitive data type or literal.

Comment: This is very important, and I would go as far to say that it supports the idea that `readonly static` is the preferred way to `const`.

Answer (score 5):

A `const` field is a `compile time` constant - you actually need code to run to determine the value of `Color.Orange` though, internally probably defined as

```
public static readonly Color Orange = new Color(...);
```

Since this cannot be computed at compile time, your only option is `readonly` which is set at runtime.

Also check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/12/03/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-static-readonly.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the technical aspects that others have mentioned (that `const` values are replaced at compile-time in the places they are used, and are required to be literals rather than `static readonly` values which are assigned and referenced at runtime) there is a semantic issue to consider.

The reason `const` values are replaced at compile-time is that `const` really does mean "constant" - as in a value that will never, ever change such as *pi* or *e*. That's why it's safe to replace them at compile-time, because the name represents a forever unchanging value.

The fact that you state...

> The purpose is simply to have a single location in which to change all of the colors for logging purposes.

...indicates that these are not semantically constant, and thus should not be defined as `const` even if it were possible to do so.

Comment: You bring up a good point. In *theory* they won't change, unless management says something like "Hey the red is too hard to read in the log window."

Answer (score 1):

You could at the very least make 'em static. A read-only *field* is otherwise just that, a field, that can only be assigned to during initilization. It makes no guarantees about the represented value being "read-only".

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, and you can't do any better (as the compiler tells you).

But do make them `static`, if they are not already.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a static Colors like this:

```
// tested with C# 5.0
static const Color ERROR = Color.FromArgb(0, 255,0);
static const Color MYPOOL = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Aqua);
```

Comment: This will not compile because a `Color` is not a compile-time constant.