# Use color paletts of excel in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, excel, colors

Is there a way to use exactly the same palettes (Larissa, Grayscale, ananke, ...) from excel in a c# WinForms application?

**Edit**

1) Larissa, Ananke, ... are palettes. See [here](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/322ac8d2-9d3b-45e0-b4e9-21ac7a04175e.png). In the pictures there is no palette named 'Larissa'. So it seems that the palettes can differ.

2) I want to be able to switch the palettes at runtime.

Comment: Using VS color picker it would take just few minutes get all needed colors and define them [as constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5381717/1997232). The only problem, that's xaml designer.

Comment: Of cours this is a possible way to do it. But i wanted to know if it can be done without defining constants and switch the palettes at runtime.

Comment: @ooorndtski Then you should specify that in your question. You only ask if it is possible to use the same colors, not that you need to do runtime switching of themes.

Comment: So `Larissa` is not a single color as I thought, but a palette? Can you provide more info about it? Screenshot, maybe some reference?

Comment: @Canis: You are right. I should have done this. I updated my question.